# Get Multiple raws selected in Jtable in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouse-listeners

Im triying to get all raws selected in table , I us the GetSelectedRaw() method to get the raw wich its selected by the user :

```
int raw_index = table.getSelectedRow();
```

but what if the user select more than one raw ??? I need to get all index of all raws selected in the table ...

I put onMoussPressed and onMoussReleased to the table :

```
int start_rows_to_delete;  // the first selected raw
int end_rows_to_delete;   // the last selected raw

private void tableMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
start_rows_to_delete = table.getSelectedRow();
} 

private void tableMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {  
end_rows_to_delete = table.getSelectedRow();
}
```

runing of prog. give me:
start_rows_to_delete = start_rows_to_delete !!!!!!

To more understande my goal , plz check this picture :

[image]

How do I do that? I googled a lot, but either I used the wrong keywords or there are no simple solutions on the internet. I hope somebody here can help me.

Best regards and thanks in advance, Fadel

Comment: please fix your keyboard (question and exclamation mark keys seem to be stuck ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRow%28%29)

> Returns the index of the first selected row, -1 if no row is selected.

Try using [`JTable#getSelectedRows`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRows%28%29), which will return an array of the selected row indicies

You may also want to take a look [`JTable#convertRowIndexToModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel%28int%29) which will convert the view index to the model index which is useful when the table is sorted.

Instead of using a `MouseListener` you should use a `ListSelectionListener` which will let you know when the selection has changed, as the use may change the selection using the keyboard, which the `MouseListener`, obviously, won't tell you about.

Check out [How to write a List Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) for more details

Comment: O.M.G !!!! Thank you @MadProgrammer :) :) It helped a lot !!! 
I will check your answer as true (y)

Comment: @Fadel Make sure you check the updates and give Rene a up vote, because his answer is also very helpful

Answer (score 3):

Use the `ListSelectionModel`.

You can get it from a table `Table.getSelectionModel()`

The `ListSelectionModel` gives you the selected indexes. With them you can get the selected objects through the [TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?javax/swing/table/TableModel.html).

Comment: Dear @Rene Link , big thnks for your help , but no result given to me when i tap: table.getL..... !!!
I used table.getSelectedRows() method and it work succufuly :) thank you dear :)